# SWC Instance name on movieclips?

Tags: actionscript-3, instance, swc

Is it possible to compile movieclips to swc with the instance name as property name? This happends when I add a dynamic text field, but i would like this also on some UI elements.

Comment: For flash.. compile to swc for use in FlashDevelop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tick the "Export for ActionScript" box in the symbol properties and give it a class name. That will make it show up in the swc.

So if you have a `Car` clip containing a `Driver` clip you will need to check "Export for actionscript" on both these clips.
If you then give the `Driver` clip an instance name it will show up as a property on your `Car`.

Comment: I know... but the instance name get's lost when compiling.. try to add a dynamic text field and give it a instance name.. now it will be a property on your class. How can i make this work for movieclips instead textfields ?

Comment: I found that this works, but I get a null object reference on for example driver. It shows up as a property.