# Embed SWC cannot access textfield

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I added a SWC with movieclip assets to my flash builder project. I can access all movieclips with dot syntax but when I try to access my textfields it throws an error saying it is `cannot access a property or method of a null object reference`

Here is my code:

```
// gameMenuLevels is a main asset.
this.object = new gameMenuLevels();
```

This all works fine, I can go two levels deep:

```
var levelString:String = "level" + Utils.zeroPad(i + 1, 3);
var level:MovieClip = this.object[levelString] as MovieClip;
var bronze:MovieClip = level.bronze as MovieClip;
```

But when I try to get my textfield:

```
(bronze.getChildByName("levelNumber") as TextField)
```

It throws the error.

Comment: It looks like your variable `bronze` is `null`. Try `trace(bronze)` and `trace(level.bronze)` and see if you get anything.

Comment: You should be able to get your text fields just by using dot syntax without using getChildByName. Like if you have a text field with instance name 'levelNumber' it should be accessible as bronze.levelNumber

Comment: That's what I assumed but it wasn't working.

Comment: @Laurent it traced it out and it was null. So let me figure that out and get back with an update.

Comment: @brenjt, make sure bronze is actually a MovieClip. If it's in fact a Sprite or a DisplayObject, the cast to MovieClip will return null.

Comment: Also, if the TextField is inside a Button, flash will strip out the instance names - I have this same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282165/problem-with-instance-names-inside-button - unfortunately no real solution for it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay with trial and error and help from this answer to another question: [SWC Instance name on movieclips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286226/swc-instance-name-on-movieclips/2290069#2290069)

I found had to give all my child elements a linkage name (export to actionscript) and an instance name. Once that was done I could then access the child elements as a property. Hopefully this helps someone else.